# Show there exists a unique monic polynomial $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ of minimum degree such that $f(a) = 0$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field, $E$ an extension field of $F$, and a in $E$ an algebraic element. Show there exists a unique monic polynomial $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ of minimum degree such that $f(a) = 0$

All I have so far is that since a is algebraic over $E$, there exists some $p(x)$ in E such that $p(a) = 0$.

I'm really struggling with these ideas in general (fields, extension fields, and algebraic extensions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two monic polynomials *of minimal degree* such that $p(a) = q(a) = 0$.  What can we say about the polynomial $p(x) - q(x)$?

---

To summarize the comments below: $a$ is meant to be an element which is algebraic *over $F$*, rather than over $E$.

Comment: I'm not sure. We can say p(x) - q(x) = 0 when x = a.

Comment: @user495422 That's one important observation.  What can you say about the degree of $p-q$?

Comment: Well, if deg(p) = m and deg(q) = n, then deg(p - q) = m - n.

Comment: @user495422 that... is not how the degree of polynomials work.  Also, see my latest edit: in our argument, we know that $p$ and $q$ are monic polynomials of the same (minimal) degree.

Comment: All I can think of in that case is that deg(p - q) = deg(p) - 1

since they're monic and of the same degree, the first term is canceled out via subtraction.

Comment: More precisely, we have $\operatorname{deg}(p - q) \leq \operatorname{deg}(p) - 1$, but yes that's the right idea!  Now: $\operatorname{deg}(p)$ is *the minimal degree* of a monic polynomial satisfying $p(a) = 0$.  What does that tell us about $p-q$?  What if we were to divide $p-q$ by its leading coefficient?

Comment: Since deg(p) is the minimum degree, any polynomial g with a degree less than deg(p) cannot be a monic polynomial satisfying g(a) = 0. I'm having a hard time seeing how this shows that p(x) is in F[x], though.

Comment: @user495422 ah, I missed that you typed that. You need to take a closer look at the definition of "algebraic".  In particular, we know that there exists a polynomial *with coefficients in $F$* such that $p(a) = 0$.  The above discussion is about polynomials in $F[x]$.

Comment: But a is algebraic over E, not F. I think. Am I wrong? That's how I parsed the question.

Comment: @user495422 Yes, you're wrong.  First, I don't think that "$a$ is algebraic over $E$" is correct usage of terminology (at least, that doesn't sound right to me).  I think you should look in the index of your text book and/or flip through your notes, and take a close look at the definition of "an algebraic element of a field extension".

Comment: So when the question says a in E is an algebraic element, what is that saying?

Comment: @user495422 I was wrong about the terminology.  However, we are certainly supposed to interpret the question as meaning that $a$ is algebraic over $F$.  In particular, any element of $E$ is *trivially* algebraic over $E$, since $x-a \in E[x]$.

Comment: Okay, that makes this a lot easier, then. Thank you. I thought I had to show that with the given conditions, a must also be algebraic over F.

Comment: I'm still having an incredibly hard time with this. 

I can show, by definition, that there exists p(x) in F[x] s.t. p(a) = 0. But how do I show that there exists some minimal monic polynomial?

Comment: @user495422 you also know that $p(x) \neq 0$, so you can divide $p$ by its leading coefficient.  So any time there is a polynomial with $p(a) = 0$, there is a monic polynomial with the same degree which is also $0$ at $a$.

Comment: Okay. So, knowing that p(x) has minimal degree, we can turn it into a monic polynomial g(x), and we can show g(x) is unique. How do I show that p(x) has minimal degree?

Comment: We have a non-empty set of polynomials (the annihilators of $a$), and the degree of every polynomial is a non-negative integer.  There must exist within that set a polynomial of minimal degree.

Comment: Okay. That's what I thought would be the case, but something about just going "let this one be the minimum one" felt a little thin. Thank you.

Comment: @user495422 Glad to help.  Be sure to "accept" this answer by clicking the $\checkmark$ if you feel that your questions have been sufficiently addressed.

Answer (score -1):

so $a \in E$ is algebraic over $F$ means there exists a monic minimal polynomial say $f(x) \in F[x]$ such that $f(a)=0$ but it is given $g(a)=0$ implies $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$ using division algorithm and minimality of $f$ having $a$ as a zero.Similarly g(x) divides f(x) , hence we get g(x)=h_1(x)*f(x)=h_1(x)*h_2(x)*g(x) implies h_1(x)*h_2(x)=1 but F[x] has only units same as F so h_1(x) and h_2(x) must be in F but f and g are minimal so h_1 and h_2 must be 1.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's hard to read. (I have edited some part, and leave the rest to you.)